# Can 2 bitcoin-cli's use the same blocksdir

Tags: development

I am trying to set up 2 clients with both using the same block directory is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

`bitcoin-cli` simply acts as a convenience interface to the JSON-RPC api of `bitcoind` - as long as you only have one instance of `bitcoind` using a given datadir, you can safely use multiple `bitcoin-cli` calls at the same time.

Comment: Right, though beware of the maximum number of concurrent calls (4 by default, adjustable with`-rpcthreads`). `bitcoind` will *ignore* any calls made above this limit.

Comment: Does this mean that by default only 4 bitcoin-cli can ever use the same blocksdir or only 4 at a time?